# Calculating mean and variance from a density kernel using Monte Carlo methods

Tags: r, statistics, mean, variance, kernel-density

Assuming a probability distribution has a density kernel of [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/irjRs.png],
what Monte Carlo methods can I use to estimate the mean and variance of the distribution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use numerical methods here. First of all, we create a function to represent your probability density function (though this is not yet scaled so that its integral is 1 over its full domain):

```r
pdf <- function(x) x^2 * exp(-x^2/4)

plot(pdf, xlim = c(0, 10))
```

[image]

To get the scaling factor to turn this into a genuine pdf, we can integrate this function over its domain of `c(0, Inf)`.

```r
integrate(pdf, 0, Inf)$value
#> [1] 3.544908
```

So now we can generate a genuine pdf by dividing our original pdf by this amount:

```r
pdf <- function(x)  x^2 * exp(-x^2/4) / 3.544908

plot(pdf, xlim = c(0, 10))
```

[image]

Now that we have a pdf, we can create a cdf with numerical integration:

```r
cdf <- function(x) sapply(x, \(i) integrate(pdf, 0, i)$value)

plot(cdf, xlim = c(0, 10))
```

[image]

The inverse of the cdf is what we need, to be able to convert a sample taken from a uniform distribution between 0 and 1 into a sample drawn from our new distribution. We can create this inverse function using `uniroot` to find where the output of our cdf matches an arbitrary number between 0 and 1:

```r
inverse_cdf <- function(p) 
{
  sapply(p, function(i) {
              uniroot(function(a) {cdf(a) - i}, c(0, 100))$root
  })
}
```

The inverse cdf looks like this:

```r
plot(inverse_cdf, xlim = c(0, 0.99))
```

[image]

We are now ready to draw a sample from our distribution:

```r
set.seed(1) # Makes this draw reproducible

x_sample <- inverse_cdf(runif(1000))
```

Now we can plot a histogram of our sample and ensure it matches the pdf:

```
hist(x_sample, freq = FALSE)

plot(function(x) pdf(x), add = TRUE, xlim = c(0, 6))
```

[image]

Now that we have a sample drawn from x, we can use the sample mean and variance as estimates for the distribution's mean and variance:

```r
mean(x_sample)
#> [1] 2.264438

var(x_sample)
#> [1] 0.9265678
```

We can increase the accuracy of these estimates by taking larger and larger samples in our call to `inverse_cdf(runif(1000))`, by increasing the 1000 to a larger number.

<sup>Created on 2021-11-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: I dunno about the general approach. If we're willing to compute the normalizing constant via numerical integration, we may as well compute the first and second moments the same way and be done with it. There are MC methods which don't require the normalizing constant -- this is considered an important point, since integrating the unnormalized density might be intractable. Since OP was given an unnormalized density, I suspect OP's instructor intended for such a method to be applied.

Comment: @RobertDodier thanks. I realize that this approach can't always be generalized, and it's a fair point that MC methods are a bit pointless for estimating the mean and variance once we have the pdf. To be honest, this was more of a stats question than a programming question, but I took the opportunity to show _one_ valid approach to this particular problem that also demonstrates some useful functions in base R. I have no real statistical training though, so please consider posting an answer that shows us a more generalizable approach. I'd love to learn more.

Comment: thank you for your flawless solution. just one question, why should we divide the PDF hypothetical function by the value of its integrate over the range of (0, Inf) for generating the genuine PDF?

Comment: @ToughGuy the area under a probability density function over its domain must equal 1. The expression you were given was only _proportional_ to the pdf (note the "proportional to" symbol between p(x) and the expression). Since the domain of p(x) is x > 0, the integral of p(x) between 0 and infinity must be 1, but the integral of the expression `x^2 * exp(-x^2/4)` is actually 3.544908. This means that 3.544908 is the constant of proportionality, so we can just divide the expression by 3.544908 to give our actual pdf. In other words, the total integral of  `x^2 * exp(-x^2/4) / 3.544908` is 1

Comment: @AllanCameron thanks for your interest. I made some comments for OP, advising MCMC in general and the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm in particular. To be honest, on looking at the problem in more detail, applying MCMC looks complex enough that it wouldn't be reasonable, at least without more guidance from the instructor. If I were OP, I'd go back and try to get some clarification before going too far.